# Burninate / retag / merge the [recover] and [recovery] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request, clean-up

The tags [recover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recover) (x106 questions) and [recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recovery) (x337 questions) have 7 collective followers, and neither have a wiki summary.  Most of the questions have to do with file and database recovery after deletion.

Should these be retagged with [data-recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) (9 followers / 138 tagged questions) and/or [file-recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-recovery) (2 / 57) where appropriate?

Should we also do the same for the [undelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undelete) (0 / 19) tag?  Side note, I wonder how many times the phrase "undelete my notepad file" has ever been said.

Comment: I just noticed: the tag _recovery_ is used 459 times and has the description "Use this tag on any questions related to data recovery" and there is the tag _data-recovery_ used 201 times and has no description.